# how to get the method fields of a typed function (Go)

Tags: methods, go

I'm wondering if it's possible to get the method fields from a typed function using reflection or by other means.
   The problem that I'm trying to solve is that I have a method which accepts a function of specific type but I need to actually transport different types and based on the type provided to execute  operations. I'm aware that I could use an interface{} value as receiver but I don't want to loose the type checking on the calling function ("GetIt")

```
package main

type ttp struct {
    Coupons string
}

func (m ttp) GetIt(x string) {
    if m.Coupons != "" {
        print(m.Coupons)
    }
}

func calculate(mth func(s string)){
    //perform calculations and update the Coupon field
    mth.Cupons = "one coupon" // is not working :(
    // execute it again with the processed value
    mth.GetIt() // is not working


}
func main() {
    m := ttp{Coupons: "something"}
    calculate(m.GetIt)
}
```

[Play](http://play.golang.org/p/X_fcIUFNS3)

Comment: Have you considered performing a [type switch](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) or a [conversion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) with a test if it succeeded?

Comment: I don't quite understand the use case here. But generally, when starting out, I wouldn't try to emulate other languages' dynamic tricks with `reflect`--either stick to the core of the type system (static types and interfaces and type switches and so on), use other packages that have done the `reflect` nastiness for you (like `encoding` packages and ORMs), or fully give in to your dynamic urges and pass `map`s around some parts of the code.

Comment: @FUZxxl the issue is that I don't know what type it is. I just need to the value of a common field and then pass that struct to a different function. I'm not sure if it makes sense.

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat define an interface that contains an accessor function for that field. Make all relevant structures implement that interface. Use a conversion to test if the object implements the interface.

Answer (score 0):

well this does not answer your exact question but it should solve your problem and cleanup the logic: push the calculate method inside the type and use a interface

https://play.golang.org/p/On_AigRYW6

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Computer interface {
    Compute(string)
}

type myp struct {
    Coupons string
}

// myp implements Computer
func (m *myp) Compute(x string) {
    m.GetIt(x)
    fmt.Println("myp")

}

type ttp struct {
    Various string
}

// ttp implements Computer
func (m *ttp) Compute(x string) {
    m.GetIt(x)
    fmt.Println("ttp")
}

func (m myp) GetIt(x string) {}
func (m ttp) GetIt(x string) {}

func main() {
    m := &myp{Coupons: "something"}
    t := &ttp{Various: "various stuff"}
    var stuff = []Computer{m, t}
    for _, c := range stuff {
        c.Compute("s")
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that Compute should receive n types. I will update the question to make it more clear...

Comment: I mean that I can't really implement the interface for each type because the scope is to encapsulate some stuff in a Compute function which should update the method fields and then execute it back like a kind of call back.